# What does "rapid-filled" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In one of my online English classes there's a lesson about the [Victoria Falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Falls) which has the following sentences:

> Today, visitors can land at the nearby airport and easily visit the falls. The adventurous can take a rafting ride down the **rapid-filled** gorges or bungee jump from the Victoria Bridge.

I did not find the word *rapid-filled* in both my dictionary and Google. Can anyone help explain?

Comment: I would leave out the hyphen.

Comment: @user3169 - I would not leave out the hyphen.  it isn't a gorge that is rapid and filled, it is a gorge that is filled with rapids.  The hyphen indicates that the two words are to be considered as one adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the *rapid* in *rapid-filled* refers to the following:

> - [rapid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rapid)
>     noun
>
>   4. Usually, **rapids**. a part of a river where the current runs very swiftly.
>        (Dictionary.com)
> - [Rapids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapids) are sections of a river where the river bed has a relatively steep gradient, causing an increase in water velocity and turbulence.
>
>   [image]
>     (Wikipedia)

So the gorges are filled with rapids.

Answer (score 1):

Rapids = quickly moving waterfalls

Filled = full of, plenty of

Rapids-filled = full of rapids